# Prevent click event after dragging container (slideshow)

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a draggable container filled with a row of images. 
Whenever I drag the container, a click event follows that opens one of the links. It would be great to disable this.

There are many questions on stackoverflow adressing click after drag events. 
But they don't seem to work, I'm guessing because in this case multiple links are dragged together **within** a container.

JQUERY so far

```
var cancelFollow = false;

$(function(){

  $(".my-gallery").click(function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (cancelFollow)
    {
      cancelFollow = false;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  $(".my-gallery").draggable({
    axis: "x",

    start: function(e, ui){},

    stop: function(e, ui){
      cancelFollow = true;
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="my-gallery">    
       <a href="img/slideshow1a.jpg">
           <img src="img/slideshow1a.jpg"/>
       </a>

       <a href="img/slideshow1b.jpg">
           <img src="img/slideshow1b.jpg"/>
       </a>      
 </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's the project by the way: http://emilpabon.driesbos.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use unbind function when you need it. [jquery unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
Not sure but check if you can use something like:

```
 html changed like ->

 <div class="my-gallery">    
   <a data-link="img/slideshow1a.jpg" href='javascript:void(0)'>
       <img src="img/slideshow1a.jpg"/>
   </a>

   <a data-link="img/slideshow1b.jpg" href='javascript:void(0)'>
       <img src="img/slideshow1b.jpg"/>
   </a>      
 </div>

 js part ->
 function thingsToDoOnclick(){
   window.location.href = $(this).data('link')
 }

 $(".my-gallery").draggable({
  axis: "x",

  start: function(e, ui){$(ui.helper).unbind('click', thingsToDoOnclick)},

  stop: function(e, ui){$(ui.helper).bind('click', thingsToDoOnclick)}
});
```

Comment: Do you mean unbind during drag? Would be great if you could give an example. Am quite a jQuery noob still!

Comment: Nope.. Slideshow becomes undraggable. I'll try variations and check the answer in a bit. Thanks!